# How to write Predicate to find X in list and make second list =X+first list

Tags: prolog

I need some clarification on this:

insertion( X, L1, L2 ) is a predicate that is true if :

1. X occurs in L1, so L1 equals L2
2. X does not occur in L1, so L2 is L1+X,

Three cases are possible  :

A. L1 is empty,

B. L1 is nonempty and starts with X,

C. L1 is non-empty and starts with something that is not X.

Below is the implementation I have tried that did not work :

```
insertion(X,[H|T1],[H,S2]):- T1\=S2,insertion(X,T1,S2).
setinsertion(X,[Head|Tail],[Head|S2]) :-
Head/=X, 
setinsertion(X,Tail,S2).
```

I have no idea why it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want 'insertion' to insert an element into the second list if it is not already present.

This works:

```
insertion(X,T,T):- member(X, T), !.
insertion(X,T,[X|T]).
```